# Get the old and recent documents from a non-incremental index (indexed documents)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, indexing

Currently I get the old and new documents as of a given date. But this can be a problem if there are multiple documents with the same dates and my intention is to use a "pagination". That is why I want to change it by using id. This id is unique and random. I would like to get the adjacent indexed documents using the id of a document instead of using a specific date, and finally getting the same result.

Currently the database is indexed as follows:

```
{
  "CreatedAt": -1
}
```

Current code:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "old": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "createdAt": {
              "$lt": ISODate("2021-03-28T03:28:21.000Z")
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 2
        }
      ],
      "new": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "createdAt": {
              "$gt": ISODate("2021-03-28T03:28:21.000Z")
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/YstxY2qc5Mq

Is it possible to achieve using document "id" instead "createdAt"?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I believe you need to use {gte & lt) or (gt & lte) otherwise you will lose records which matched your timestamp. Secondly by default _id is indexed and if you are using default _id i.e ObjectId then though timestamp is same it will be in order of insertion if you sort by _id or createdAt.

Also if you need recent old and recent new from given time then you can use below:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/arimc8YjJit

if you need to sort documents with same time then use sorting with _id along with createdAt https://mongoplayground.net/p/LpI0hPTkvKC

Comment: [1/3] I want to save the id of last message read and then, use it to query old and new messages from that message. I don't want to use "createdAt" field to query because can be multiple messages that have same "createdAt" field and if I want to do a pagination, i need to use unique field to dont retreive same messages in later pages.

Comment: [2/3] Imagine that there are 4 messages that have "createdAt" equal to  ( 11/11/2021 12:12:12  ), id from 2-5:

*createdAt: 10/09/2021 10:03:21, id = 1
*createdAt: 11/11/2021 12:12:12, id = 2
*createdAt: 11/11/2021 12:12:12, id = 3
*createdAt: 11/11/2021 12:12:12, id = 4
*createdAt: 11/11/2021 12:12:12, id = 5
*createdAt: 12/12/2021 05:05:03, id = 6

Retreiveng 1 message $lt  11/11/2021 12:12:12 and 1 $gte 12:12:12 will get following result:
*createdAt: 10/09/2021 10:03:21, id = 1
*createdAt: 11/11/2021 12:12:12, id = 2

Comment: [3/3] now i want to do next pagination, problem that if we use dates, it will use another time 11/11/2021 12:12:12 and will get same result instead:
*createdAt: 11/11/2021 12:12:12, id = 3
*createdAt: 11/11/2021 12:12:12, id = 4

Comment: okay let say you want to get data for time 11/11/2021 12:12:12 then you will get max ID for that timestamp and run aggregation based on _id(in this example its 5)  https://mongoplayground.net/p/w_bDKmiP0Fg
 first one is using skip limit, here for each page you will skip n*page size here page size is 2 ( limit =2), so for page one skip is 0, page 2 is 1*2 =2 for page 3 its 2*2=4 and so on..
 
 if you don't want to skip then you need to keep track of max id for new and least id for old, for example for page 2 you will use lt 4 & gt 7 and based on result again you will track new min max ids.